# Find $a$ such that $E[(X-a)^4]$ is minimised

Tags: probability, expectation

Given X is a symmetrical random variable and $E[X^4]$ exists. Find $a$ such that $E[(X-a)^4]$ is minimised.

The fact, X is symmetrical, means the odd central moments are $0$. I expanded the expression, worked out the derivative and set it to $0$. I ended up with an answer of $a^2 = -3E[X^2]$. I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Alternatively, if you differentiate without expanding and set to zero you get $E[(X-a)^3]=0,$ which is clearly zero when $a=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is (almost) correct.

\begin{align}
E[(X-a)^4] &= a^4 + 4a^3E[X]+ 6a^2E[X^2] + 4a^3E[X] + E[X^4] \\
 &= a^4 + 6a^2E[X^2] + E[X^4]
\end{align}

because, as you mention yourself, "the odd central moments are 0", i.e.,
$$
E[X] = E[X^3] = 0
$$

and thus

$$
\frac{d}{da}E[(X-a)^4] = 4a^3 + 12aE[X^2]
$$

This is $0$ only when $a=0$ (the other 2 roots of the cubic polynomial are the complex conjugates you found).

Since the derivative changes sign when $a=0$, this is indeed, an extreme value, and since the change is from negative (function is decreasing) to positive (function is increasing), this is a **minimum**.

Thus the answer is $a=0$.

Comment: Ah thanks, you're the best!

Comment: here symmetry dictates `E[X]=0`

Comment: @Eli.Z: You are welcome. If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you should [close it by accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215439).

Comment: Thanks again! It's my first time posting.

Comment: @karakfa: yes, both the question and the answer mention that. So?